# Error : ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException , occurs when uploading CSV file in springBoot

Tags: java, arrays, spring-boot, csv, opencsv

I'm working on spring Boot project, where I need to import data from CSV file when adding guest to my system.

Here is my Guest Entity:

```
package com.example.attendingsystembackend.model;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@Entity
public class Guest {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String firstName;
    @NotNull
    private String lastName;
    @NotBlank(message = "Company email cannot be blank")
    private String company_email;

    private String phoneNumber;
    private String position;

    @Lob
    private byte[] image;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getCompany_email() {
        return company_email;
    }

    public void setCompany_email(String company_email) {
        this.company_email = company_email;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public String getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    public void setPosition(String position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    public byte[] getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(byte[] image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
}
```

This is the GuestController and here in saveGuest method is wrote to match when I save guest manually. and I have wrote post method to upload csv file.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/guest")
@CrossOrigin("http://localhost:3000")
public class GuestController {

    private final GuestRepository guestRepository;
    private final GuestService guestService;
    private final CSVParser csvParser;

    @Autowired
    public GuestController(GuestRepository guestRepository, GuestService guestService, CSVParser csvParser) {
        this.guestRepository = guestRepository;
        this.guestService = guestService;
        this.csvParser = csvParser;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "saveGuest", consumes = { "multipart/form-data" })
    public ResponseEntity<String> saveGuest(
            @RequestParam(value = "file", required = false) MultipartFile file,
            @RequestParam(value = "body") String body
    ) {
        try {
            // Create an ObjectMapper instance and register the Java 8 date/time module
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());

            // Parse the JSON string into an Event object
            Guest guest = mapper.readValue(body, Guest.class);

            // Call the service method with the file and event object
            guestService.saveGuest(file, guest);

            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK)
                    .body(String.format("Guest saved successfully with file: %s", file != null ? file.getOriginalFilename() : "none"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
                    .body("Invalid request body");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                    .body(String.format("Failed to save event: %s", e.getMessage()));
        }
    }


    @PostMapping("/upload")
    public ResponseEntity<String> uploadCSV(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException, CsvValidationException {
        List<Guest> guests = csvParser.parseCSV(file);

        for (Guest guest : guests) {
            guestService.saveGuest(null,guest);
        }

        return ResponseEntity.ok(String.format("Guests saved successfully from file: %s", file.getOriginalFilename()));
    }



}
```

And here is my csvParser service class :

```
@Service
public class CSVParser {

    public List<Guest> parseCSV(MultipartFile file) throws IOException, CsvValidationException {
        List<Guest> guests = new ArrayList<>();

        try (CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(file.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {
            String[] line;
            reader.readNext(); // Skip the header line

            while ((line = reader.readNext()) != null) {
                Guest guest = new Guest();
                guest.setFirstName(line[0]);
                guest.setLastName(line[1]);
                guest.setPhoneNumber(line[2]);
                guest.setCompany_email(line[3]);
                guest.setPosition(line[4]);

                guests.add(guest);
            }
        }

        return guests;
    }
}
```

As per the initial stage I tried to upload csv file with firstName,lastName,phoneNumber,company_email and position. I haven't passed image with csv and need to do that in future.

So following you can see the structure of my csv file:
[image]

And I tried to send this csv file using postman as follows:
[image]

But I'm getting the an error saying `ArrayIndexOutOfBound Exception`.Here is my error that I'm getting,

```
2023-05-29T23:35:22.630+05:30 ERROR 2149 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 3 out of bounds for length 3] with root cause

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 3 out of bounds for length 3
    at com.example.attendingsystembackend.utils.CSVParser.parseCSV(CSVParser.java:30) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.attendingsystembackend.controller.GuestController.uploadCSV(GuestController.java:127) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:152) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1081) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:914) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:563) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:631) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:6.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

What is the cause Behind this? If I add column as `image` and set it to null in csv file and tried to upload it, the same error is occured.Can someone help me in this issue?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: you are trying to parse the .csv file. but you sending .ods file type in postman which causes the error. for avoiding such mismatch extension types, i would suggest the apache tika mime type validation in your controller layer.

Comment: Set a breakpoint in the backend and check if your CSV reader is correctly splitting the lines. Also check if you are *really* sending a text file. The filename in postman suggests otherwise.